# Save set image as background

Tags: android

I am trying to save an image that I set as the background of an activity here:

```
         @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
     private void setBackgroundImage(Bitmap bitmap) { 
     RelativeLayout yourBackgroundView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_drag_and_drop_app); 

     Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap); 

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) { 
     yourBackgroundView.setBackgroundDrawable(d); 
     } else { 
     yourBackgroundView.setBackground(d); 
     Log.d("Drag_and_Drop_App", "Background is set");
     } 
     }
```

So that when the user closes the program and reopens it, that image is still set as the background until the user changes it.

It's made so that the user chooses an image, and then that image shows into an imageView (as a preview), and then when a button called "set background" is pressed, that image in the imageView is set as the background.

I have it saved right now where it saves the imagePath of the image but that only saves it into the imageView (preview) and not saves it where it keeps that image as the background.

How can I keep that image as the background when it is set?

Comment: You can possibly use SharedPreferences and save the user settings accordingly.

Comment: Would something such as `yourBackgroundView.setBackground(d); 
      SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      Editor edit=shre.edit();
      d.toString();
      edit.putString("d","/sdcard/imh.jpeg");
      edit.commit();
      Log.d("Drag_and_Drop_App", "Background is set");
      } ` work?